# Enderton Set Theory Confusing Definitions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm reading Elements of Set Theory by Enderton and I'm having trouble understand the following (Section - set an informal view)

> Take $V_0$ to be the set of all atoms (I'm referring to the set theoretic atom) and define $V_{n+1} = V_n \cup \mathcal P V_{n}$.
>
> Let $x \in V_{a+1}$ and let $V_{b + 1}$ be higher in hierarchy than $V_{a+1}$. Then $x$ must be a member of $V_{b+1}$.

---

My problems

1. Why is $V_{n + 1}$ defined as $V_n \cup \mathcal P V_{n}$ instead of just $\mathcal P V_{n}$?.
2. How will $x$ be a member of $V_{b+1}$. The closest I can think of is that $\overset{b-a}{\overbrace{ \{\cdots\{}} x \overset{b-a}{\overbrace{ \}\cdots\} }} \in V_{b + 1}$.

Comment: Are you sure that the second quotation is correct? The $y$ in the first part of it is an orphan that seems to have no relevance to the rest of it.

Comment: I have skimmed some details. You can read the section in the [sample provided by amazon](https://www.amazon.com/Elements-Set-Theory-Herbert-Enderton/dp/0122384407) on page 7. $y$ was included accidentally and doesn't have any relevance for this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your first question, look at $V_1$: no atom is a subset of $V_0$, so $V_0\cap\wp(V_0)=\varnothing$, but we want $V_0$ to be a subset of $V_1$. The minimal way to ensure this is to let $V_1=V_0\cup\wp(V_0)$. Similar comments apply to the higher levels of the hierarchy.

If $x\in V_{a+1}$, then $x\in V_{a+1}\cup\wp(V_{a+1})=V_{a+2}$, and a straightforward induction shows that $x\in V_{a+n}$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$. You’ll have to wait until you get to the transfinite ordinal numbers to carry the induction any further, but it turns out that one can.

Comment: Oh. It makes sense. Thanks a lot for the answer. It turns out that I incorrectly understood how union works.

Comment: @Yasharyan: You’re welcome.