# Set union its power set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$$V_{a+1} = V_a\cup\mathscr P\,V_a$$
If we define like above when $a$ is nonnegative integer and let $V_0$ be any set, how to prove $V_a = V_0\cup\mathscr P\,V_{a-1}$? 
Intuitively $V_0$ will suffice because $V_{a-1}$ has $a-1$ layer that each ($a-2$)th layer automatically form ($a-1$)th layer by power set operation. But my explanation is very abstract and sounds so ambiguous. How to prove it strictly?

Comment: Closely Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2023775/enderton-set-theory-confusing-definitions

Comment: Have you tried mathematical induction?

Comment: The claim holds for $a=1$ by definition. Now assume $V_{a}=V_0\cup \mathscr P V_{a-1}$, then using the first definition, what is $V_{a+1}$? Maybe first prove that $X\subset Y$ implies $\mathscr PX\subset \mathscr PY$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$V_1 = V_0 \cup \mathcal P(V_0)$. Assume $V_{n} = V_0\cup \mathcal P(V_{n-1})$, then
$$ V_{n+1} = V_{n} \cup \mathcal P(V_n) = V_0 \cup \mathcal P(V_{n-1})\cup \mathcal P(V_n). $$
Note that $\mathcal P(V_{n-1}) \subseteq \mathcal P(V_n)$. Indeed, take $x\in V_{n-1}$. Then $x\in V_{n-1}\cup \mathcal P(V_{n-1}) = V_n$.

Comment: Thank you I got your answer. I was confused because if we start from $V_{n+1} = V_0\cup\mathcal P(V_n)$, things get more complex. We have a power set of union of two sets now, which is $V_{n+1} = V_0\cup\mathcal P(V_n) = V_0\cup\mathcal P(V_0\cup\mathcal P(V_{n-1}))$.